# how to check which elements of an array match relative to position

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to create a function or two that will be able to check the elements of an array and output wheater the elements of the two arrays are identical (ie same number and identical position is present), or the number is present but does not match the same position as the other array. Basically, I'm attempting to recreate a simple game called [mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). The main problem im having is a case senarior when say the right answer is [1,2,3,4] and the user will guess [0,1,1,1], my function will out put that the number 1 is present 3 times, and I need to figure out how to just have it say the number 1 is present 1 time. Here is the function that checks the arrays:

```
function make_move(guess, answ){
    var myguess = document.getElementById("mymoves");

    var correct_number_correct_spot= 0;
    var correct_number_wrong_spot= 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {

        if(answ[i] == guess[i]){
            ++correct_number_correct_spot;
            }
        else if(answ[i] !== guess[i] && $.inArray(guess[i], answ) !== -1){
            ++correct_number_wrong_spot;
           }
        }

     console.log(answ);
        console.log(guess);


    myguess.innerHTML += correct_number_correct_spot + " were right!" +correct_number_wrong_spot+ "there but not in the right order";

}
```

Comment: The easiest way using the current code, if acceptable, is to use the index returned by inArray to reset the value in answer (same for the index in the correct spot). eg, setting the answer on the found index to -1. However if that means the original answer array is altered, it would have to be cloned first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the count of `missed` numbers in an object, and subtract the guessed ones that appear in the answer. Then you can calculate the `correct_number_wrong_spot` subtracting the number of `correct_number_correct_spot` and the missed ones.

```
function make_move(guess, answ){
    var myguess = document.getElementById("mymoves");

    var correct_number_correct_spot = 0;

    // Initialize missed counts to the numbers in the answer.
    var correct_number_wrong_spot = answ.length;
    var missed = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < answ.length; j++) {
        missed[answ[j]] = (missed[answ[j]] || 0) + 1;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < answ.length; ++i)
    {     
        if(answ[i] == guess[i]){
            ++correct_number_correct_spot;
        }
        // Subtract the guessed numbers from the missed counts.
        if (guess[i] in missed) {
            missed[guess[i]] = Math.max(0, missed[guess[i]] - 1);
        }
    }

    // Subtract the correctly spotted numbers.  
    correct_number_wrong_spot -= correct_number_correct_spot;
    // Subtract the remaining missed numbers.
    for (var number in missed) {
        correct_number_wrong_spot -= missed[number];
    }

    console.log(answ);
    console.log(guess);

    myguess.innerHTML += correct_number_correct_spot + " were right!" +correct_number_wrong_spot+ "there but not in the right order";
}
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hhptmxbr/1/)

EDIT: My try to explain doubts exposed in the comments:

> would you mind explining how this code works: for (var j = 0; j < answ.length; j++) { missed[answ[j]] = (missed[answ[j]] || 0) + 1; }

```
missed[answ[j]] = (missed[answ[j]] || 0) + 1;
```

This is a quick way to increment the count for a number or initialize it to 0 if it doesn't exists yet. More or less the statement works like this:

If `missed[answ[j]]` is undefined then it is *[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)* and hence the `||` (or operator) evaluates to the `0`. Otherwise, if we already have a value greater than `0`, then it is *[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)* and the `||` evaluates to the contained number.

If it looks weird, you can replace this line with:

```
if (!(answ[j] in missed)) {
    missed[answ[j]] = 0;
}
missed[answ[j]] += 1;
```

> also if (guess[i] in missed) { missed[guess[i]] = Math.max(0, missed[guess[i]] - 1);

```
missed[guess[i]] = Math.max(0, missed[guess[i]] - 1);
```

In this case I use `Math.max` to make sure we don't subtract below `0`. We don't want repeated numbers in the guess that exceeds the number of those present in the answer count. I mean, we subtract at most until the number of repeated numbers in the answer.

```
if (missed[guess[i]] > 0) {
    missed[guess[i]] -= 1;
}
```

Comment: havent seen the 'in' keyword before , can you explain how this is being used? it looks like its checkin it creates that object property then check if it exsits, interesting.

Comment: Just tried this combo and it didnt quite work, but almost: this was the answer: ["1", "5", "6", "4"] and i guessed 2424. It stated 1 were right!1there but not in the right order. So its counting the twice.

Comment: @codemonkey Check the update. I reworked a little bit your code to keep the count of missed numbers in order to be able to calculate the `correct_number_wrong_spot`.

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner

Comment: would you mind explining how this code works: for (var j = 0; j < answ.length; j++) {
        missed[answ[j]] = (missed[answ[j]] || 0) + 1;
    }

Comment: also if (guess[i] in missed) {
            missed[guess[i]] = Math.max(0, missed[guess[i]] - 1);

Comment: thanks really helpful im still trying to understand algorthims any recommendation for learning it better?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncc4L2px/1/)!

Without changing your original function too much, you can use an object as a map to keep track of which numbers you have already matched.

```
var number_matched = {};
// ...
if(!number_matched[guess[i]]) {
    number_matched[guess[i]] = true;
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen an object being used like an array, didn't knw you could do number_matched[guesss[i]] how does that work

Comment: This is just referencing object property using bracket notation. See more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: just tried a few examples, it looks really lose but still slightly off for example: ans = ["3", "6", "3", "4"] guess = 2353 only says 1 number there but wrong spot, but it should say 2 numbers there but in wrong spot.